# CIDR and number of ip-addresses

Tags: cidr

I read `10.240.0.0/24` can host to up 254 ip-addresses. How?
How do I intuitively understand what `/24` is doing here to help give 254 unique ip-addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL; DR;

A short way to compute the number of hosts would be

```
2 ^ ( 32 - 24 ) - 2 = 256
```

Because:

1. We are doing bit operations (`0`, `1`, two possible values)
2. An IP is a set of 4 octet, when an octet is 8 bits (`4 * 8 = 32`)
3. `24` is your CIDR
4. There is two reserved IP on every subnet, the broadcast address and the subnet zero, they shouldn't be used for hosts

---

CIDR is computed with the help of bitwise operations.

An IP is a set of 4 octet, each separated with a dot.

```
255.255.255.255
=
11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111
```

When you specify a CIDR of `/24` you are asking for a subnet for your IPs with a mask that would be padded with **24** bits set to **1**

```
11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000
=
255.255.255.0
```

Your IP is

```
10.240.0.0
=
00001010.11110000.00000000.00000000
```

Now we can apply a bitwise AND between your IP and your subnet

```
11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000
&
00001010.11110000.00000000.00000000
=
00001010.11110000.00000000.00000000
```

So you end up with `10.240.0.0` being your IP prefix.
The same subnet could be applied to subsequent IPs

`10.240.0.1`

```
11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000
&
00001010.11110000.00000000.00000001
=
00001010.11110000.00000000.00000000
```

Giving the same `10.240.0.0` IP prefix

`10.240.0.2`

```
11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000
&
00001010.11110000.00000000.00000010
=
00001010.11110000.00000000.00000000
```

Giving the same `10.240.0.0` IP prefix
And so on, and so forth

All in all, the bitwise operation is pretty straight forward:

- each time you have a `0 & x` it will equal `0`
- each time you have a `1 & x` it will equal `x`

So that means that with `10.240.0.0/24`, you have a subnet of `255.255.255.0` and so a range of IP from `10.240.0.0` up to `10.240.0.255`.

That still gives you 256 possible addresses you would say?

Well, yes, but you have to remember that in IPv4, you have two addresses that are not usable:

- the subnet zero (the first address of your range)
- and the broadcast address (the last address of your range)

> Special Addresses:
>
> From the Assigned Numbers memo [Reynolds, J., and J. Postel, "Assigned Numbers", RFC-943, USC/Information Sciences Institute, April 1985.]:
>
> "In certain contexts, it is useful to have fixed addresses
> with functional significance rather than as identifiers of
> specific hosts.  When such usage is called for, the address
> zero is to be interpreted as meaning "this", as in "this
> network".  The address of all ones are to be interpreted as
> meaning "all", as in "all hosts".  For example, the address
> 128.9.255.255 could be interpreted as meaning all hosts on
> the network 128.9.  Or, the address 0.0.0.37 could be
> interpreted as meaning host 37 on this network."
>
> It is useful to preserve and extend the interpretation of these
> special addresses in subnetted networks.  This means the values
> of all zeros and all ones in the subnet field should not be
> assigned to actual (physical) subnets.

*Source:* https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc950.txt

So now, if you do `256 - 2`, you have your `254` available hosts.

To sum up:

- CIDR: `10.240.0.0/24`
- Subnet mask: `255.255.255.0` (24 times a `1` when the IP is shown as groups of octet)
- IP range: `10.240.0.0` - `10.240.0.255`
- Subnet zero: `10.240.0.0`
- Broadcast address: `10.240.0.255`
- Hosts IP range:`10.240.0.1` - `10.240.0.254`

Comment: Thank you very much. I was initially hesitant to ask this question, thinking that moderators will shut-me-off.  Your answer makes SO still relevant and you have saved me years of confusion with a direct and complete answer to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^((10\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(172\.(1[6-9]|[2-3][0-1])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(192\.168\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))$/gm
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).